# Segue data from VC to TabBar to VC (iOS)

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I have a project with storyboard that I changed recently.

Before it was VC -> VC1 -> VC2  and was using this code to segue data between the ViewControllers

```
if([segue.identified isEqualToString:@"SegueData"]){
   StoreViewController *svc = [segue destinationViewController];
   NSIndexPath *path = [allStoresTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
   Stores *s = [stores objectAtIndex:path.row];
   [svc setCurrentStores:s];
}
```

Now I need to pass that data from VC -> TabBar -> VC1, VC2

How can I do that now?

I've tried this code from here that is similar to my problem (http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2884) but app crashed when running.

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = segue.destinationController;

UINavigationController *navController1 = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
StoreViewController *svc= navController1.topViewController;
NSIndexPath *path = [allStoresTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
Stores *s = [stores objectAtIndex:path.row];
[svc setCurrentStores:s];
```

Also this line is causing the crash

```
StoreViewController *svc= navController1.topViewController;
```

gives me the warning "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'StoreViewController * _strong' with an expression of type 'UIViewController*'

Comment: What about using UITabBarController's viewControllers property? It contains all child view controllers of the tab bar controller.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: The viewControllers property gives you access the each VC in the tab bar. You could do something like this: self.tabBarController.viewControllers[X] to access any other VC and exchange data between them.

Comment: That would work for passing the data between each VC in the tab bar, correct? But what I want to do is I have a seperate VC that has data and then pass it to the TabBarController.

Comment: This should be working if everything is set up properly in IB. What kind of segue are you doing from VC to TabBar? You should log navController1 and svc to make sure neither is nil. That warning shouldn't cause a crash -- you can silence it by casting navController1.topViewController to StoreViewController. Are you getting a crash message?

Comment: Maybe I am not hooking up something properly in IB.I'm using a push segue from VC to TabBar. This is the crash message. [StoreViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa838b80
2013-03-16 17:22:56.403 Benitos[2667:14f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[StoreViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa838b80'

Comment: Do you have more than one navigation controller. One that VC is embedded in, and one that svc is embedded in? log tabBarController as the second line in what you posted, and see what it gives you.

Comment: I have a NC->VC->TBC->VC1(StoreViewController),VC2. Also if I log the description for TBC and navController1 I get this. 2013-03-16 17:36:42.698 Benitos[2928:14f03] <UITabBarController: 0x93e6080>
2013-03-16 17:36:42.700 Benitos[2928:14f03] <StoreViewController: 0x9377dd0>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your problem is the line, because there is no navigation controller at index 0, that's where your StoreViewController is:

```
UINavigationController *navController1 = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Just change that line to:

```
StoreViewController *scv = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

And delete the line that starts StoreViewController = *svc ....